# Conditional editing of large text file using sed

Tags: sed, conditional-statements

in a large text file (650,000 lines, format GEDCOM, Lubuntu2204) I am trying to selectively edit certain lines based on simple conditions.
The logic is:

```
if a line contains the text "1 DEAT"
then
    while the first character of the next line is not equal to "1"
    do
        if the line contains the text "2 DATE BET"
        then
            substitute "BET" with "AFT"
        endif
    enddo
endif
```

I have looked at "sed" but my knowledge of its use is not sufficient.
I have also looked at using a shell command, same problem!
Can somebody indicate the simplest way to do this?
Here is an example of the text to be scanned.
I would like the command to change the 4th, 13th, and 23rd lines.

```
1 BIRT
2 DATE ABT 1736
1 DEAT
2 DATE BET JUN 1793 AND SEP 1823
1 NAME Giuliano /VULTAGGIO/
2 GIVN Giuliano
2 SURN VULTAGGIO
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE ABT 1676
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
1 DEAT
2 DATE BET 3 SEP 1730 AND 7 APR 1732
1 BIRT
2 DATE BET 1627 AND 1633
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
1 PROP dichiarazione dei RIveli
2 DATE 14 AUG 1681
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
1 DEAT
2 CAUS sepolto nella chiesa della confraternita di S. Martino
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
2 DATE BET 25 MAY 1713 AND 30 MAY 1720
1 FAMS @F8737@
```

thanks!

I have checked the sed manual and examples.

Comment: sorry, posting the example removed the formatting. Basically each line starts with either the number 1 or the number 2, 24 lines were posted

Comment: Why write it _specifically_ in sed? Why not awk? python?

Comment: No specific reason, I thought sed was the right tool, but if there is a simple solution using awk or python, please can you indicate what to do?

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain how it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SED script suggestion:

(file `cmd.sed`)

```
/^1 DEAT/!b
:loop
n
/^1/b
/2 DATE BET/s/BET/AFT/
b loop
```

Based on the input you provided, `sed -f cmd.sed INPUTFILE` should produce:

```
1 BIRT
2 DATE ABT 1736
1 DEAT
2 DATE AFT JUN 1793 AND SEP 1823
1 NAME Giuliano /VULTAGGIO/
2 GIVN Giuliano
2 SURN VULTAGGIO
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE ABT 1676
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
1 DEAT
2 DATE AFT 3 SEP 1730 AND 7 APR 1732
1 BIRT
2 DATE BET 1627 AND 1633
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
1 PROP dichiarazione dei RIveli
2 DATE 14 AUG 1681
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
1 DEAT
2 CAUS sepolto nella chiesa della confraternita di S. Martino
2 PLAC Erice, Trapani, Sicilia, Italy
2 DATE AFT 25 MAY 1713 AND 30 MAY 1720
1 FAMS @F8737@
```

Tested with GNU SED in POSIX mode under Debian 11.

Hope that helps!

*P.S. It was nice of you to include an algorithm to give a precise description of your requirements!*

Comment: Perfect! I just tried it on the file with 650,000 lines and it solved the problem! Thank you so much